# Codesign fails during export using a launchd runner

Tags: keychain, launchd, codesign

When using fastlane to build and export an app all of our build machines have started failing to `codesign` during the export process. The only thing that has changed is the recent expiration of certificates related to TestFlight deployments that were regenerated by fastlane.

The builder runs as a `launchd` service that starts `gitlab-runner`.

I have cleared all expired certificates and invalid provisioning profiles from the keychains and validate the complete certificate chain exists in each.

I have written a stripped down example of the issue, a simple script `runner.sh` to illustrate the problem and pretend to be the CI runner:

##### `runner.sh`

```
# Prepare to codesign
security unlock-keychain CodeSigning.keychain
# Codesign
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv --force --sign <HASH> ./MySDK.framework
```

When run from the shell EXPORT SUCCESS, but when run from launchd EXPORT FAILED. The clues:

> Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer

and `errSecInternalComponent`

However, this works perfectly and worked right up until recently. Did Apple break keychains for launchd?

###### `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.runner.plist`

```
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.example.runner</string>
<key>SessionCreate</key><true/>
<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>builder</string>
<key>GroupName</key>
<string>staff</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stdout</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>./runner.sh</string>
</array>
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Users/builder/path/to/runner</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WWDR Intermediates must be in the System.keychain?!

After 3-weeks of messing around with keychains, rewriting our codesign scripts to directly call the Security.framework CoreFoundtion APIs, validating keychain dumps for correct trusted app and partition list settings and testing countless other theories, it is this simple, you can no longer have the WWDR Intermediates in any keychain other than the `System.keychain`. Once installed there, it magically works.

#### Download all of the Worldwide Developer Relations certificates

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

This is a change made by Apple in newer versions of the keychain search mechanism and maybe related to the deprecation of the custom keychain APIs in the Security.framework.

#### Keychain Services API documentation

Just look at all of the deprecated APIs. This effectively kills off custom keychains.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychains?language=objc

#### Installation

As an aside to the solution, the next bit of pain is getting these certificates into the `System.keychain`. Apple has gone out of its way to make remote administration of dozens of machines as painful as possible.

```
sudo security import ../WWDRIntermediates.p7b -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

I downloaded all of the WWDR certificates into a `.p7b` and imported them.

### Apple's hostility towards CLI administration

Deploying certificates to the System keychain is now best handled using an MDM server like `Jamf` or `Kandji`. Increasingly normal administrative functions like macOS updates and importing certificates to the System keychain are either impossible using ansible/command-line.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I added Apple root certificates one by one:

```
sudo security import AppleWWDRCA.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
sudo security import AppleWWDRCAG2.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
sudo security import AppleWWDRCAG3.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
sudo security import AppleWWDRCAG5.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
sudo security import AppleWWDRCAG6.cer -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).